# scaffolding template for creating repositories

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, repository-pattern, scaffolding

I'm a new comer to the `Scaffold` world to build `repositories` creating the CRUD operations.

There are a lot of scaffolding templates ,I'm so confused which one will suit my requirement .

- I use `asp.net web forms` (not asp.net MVC)
- I use `Entity Framework 6` as ORM .

---

I want some help to clarify the main pillars we select one scaffolding template over one and what's the proper one for my case ?

NOTE : Right now i use `T4Scaffolding` .

Comment: Hey @Anyname Donotcare could you specify the names of templates which are confusing you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can use T4Scaffolding, as you already do. But why are you using a "scaffold"? I created my crud app with entity framework without scaffolding anything.

Anyway, the scaffolding tools are all very similar, so T4Scaffolding is perfect, IMHO.

I think you can find interesting [this](https://xsockets.net/t4scaffolding-is-alive-again/) and [this](http://www.asp.net/visual-studio/overview/2013/aspnet-scaffolding-overview).

Let me know if you have other questions.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are trying to generate repositories for each model class. If that's the case, my advice will be don't. Moreover, don't be tempted by [Generic Repositories (anti-pattern)](http://www.ben-morris.com/why-the-generic-repository-is-just-a-lazy-anti-pattern/) as well.

**For Scaffolding**
If you must use scaffolding for generating repositories around your model classes, you may refer to [this link for scaffolding repositories](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/04/06/mvcscaffolding-overriding-the-t4-templates/) using T4Scaffolding.

*Note:*
If you're using Visual Studio 2013/2015, you would have to use the [T4Scaffolding.VS2015](https://www.nuget.org/packages/T4Scaffolding.VS2015/) nuget package instead of the older [T4Scaffolding](https://www.nuget.org/packages/T4Scaffolding/) package (for older versions of VS).

**Aggregate Roots**
Firstly, repositories are created on aggregate roots and not per class.
Secondly, although debatable, but EF already implements these patterns.

You many want to read more on repositories; refer t the Matrin Fowler's [excellent post](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html).

**Why Use Repositories anyway?**
Also, there are a bunch of people against it as well *importantly for good reasons*.

See [Rob Conery's](http://rob.conery.io/2014/03/04/repositories-and-unitofwork-are-not-a-good-idea/) post on it. Although, I would prefer using the below solution instead of the one recommended in the post.

**The alternate?**
BTW, you should consider using commands or tasks instead of respositories. Something like [Ayende's post](https://ayende.com/blog/154113/limit-your-abstractions-commands-vs-tasks-did-you-forget-the-workflow). Of course, you should evaluate your case and come up with your reasons to adopt it. It's just a suggestion, probably a good one ;)